# mail utility sends the message, but django no

Tags: django, email, smtp, sendmail, centos6

I have the some problem. I want to send email via django application, but i can't: "smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (451, 'Temporary local problem - please try later')}

So, i tried to send via mail utility:

```
 echo -ne "Some test body letter" | mail -s "Test subject" '<my email>'
```

and it sends the email on my email address.

But the following script print error messages:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import time
import urllib2
import django
from datetime import datetime

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
os.environ['EMAIL_BACKEND'] = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
os.environ['EMAIL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
django.setup()

from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

import time
import sys
import datetime 
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

from django.core.mail import send_mail

import smtplib


subject, from_email, to = 'Test subject', 'root@<server hostname>', '<my email>'

html_content = "Some test body letter"

print "Attempt 1. smtplib"
try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(from_email, [to], html_content)
    s.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: %s" % str(e)

print "Attempt 2. send_mail"
try:
    send_mail(
        subject,
        html_content,
        from_email,
        [to],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: %s" % str(e)


print "Attempt 3. EmailMultiAlternatives"
try:
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR: %s" % str(e)
```

Output:

```
Attempt 1. smtplib
ERROR: {'<my email>': (451, 'Temporary local problem - please try later')}
Attempt 2. send_mail
ERROR: {u'<my email>': (451, 'Temporary local problem - please try later')}
Attempt 3. EmailMultiAlternatives
ERROR: {u'<my email>': (451, 'Temporary local problem - please try later')}
```

Help me, please!!!

Server CentOS 6, Django --- 1.9.

**Updated.**
Fix it. Just install postfix and change port for it and everything done.
There is the [source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6).

Comment: Do you actually have an smtp server running on your machine?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sure

    telnet 127.0.0.1 25
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to 127.0.0.1.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    220 <hostname> ESMTP Exim 4.84_2 Tue, 04 Jul 2017 09:50:54 -0400